# Error in Insert into select from table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

We are converting the SQL queries in our system to HQL to make our system database independent. We are facing problem converting insert queries from SQL to HQL. Following is one of the query where we are facing problems.

We have converted the query to HQL:

```
<query name="Basoseext2TO_CopyFromExtrFile">
       insert into Basoseext2TO(id.location,id.masterco,id.symbol,id.policyno,id.module,id.filename,id.thedata)
       select 
       substring(id.thedata, 1, 2),
       substring(id.thedata, 3, 2),
       substring(id.thedata, 5, 3),
       substring(id.thedata, 8, 7),
       substring(id.thedata, 15, 2),
       substring(id.thedata, 17, 10),
       substring(id.thedata, 27, 3976)
       from com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.ExtrfileTO ExtrfileTO
</query>
```

Getting the following exceptions at startup

```
[org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter](ERROR): <AST>:2:36: unexpected AST node: .
    [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter](ERROR): <AST>:2:36: unexpected AST node: .
    <AST>:2:36: unexpected AST node: .
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.insertablePropertySpec(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:984)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.intoClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:849)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.insertStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:497)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:271)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1081)
           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:519)
           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1798)
           at bphx.c2ab.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:216)
           at bphx.c2ab.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:462)
           at bphx.c2ab.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory$1.run(HibernateSessionFactory.java:157)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    2.   
           org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:  of: com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Basoseext2TO [
           insert into Basoseext2TO(id.location,id.masterco,id.symbol,id.policyno,id.module,id.filename,id.thedata)
           select 
           substring(id.thedata, 1, 2),
           substring(id.thedata, 3, 2),
           substring(id.thedata, 5, 3),
           substring(id.thedata, 8, 7),
           substring(id.thedata, 15, 2),
           substring(id.thedata, 17, 10),
           substring(id.thedata, 27, 3976)
           from com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.ExtrfileTO ExtrfileTO
    ]
           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77) 
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1985)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IntoClause.isSuperclassProperty(IntoClause.java:229)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IntoClause.visitPropertySpecNodes(IntoClause.java:171)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IntoClause.initializeColumns(IntoClause.java:153)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IntoClause.initialize(IntoClause.java:65)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createIntoClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1154)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.intoClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:857)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.insertStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:497)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:271)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1081)
           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:519)
           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1798)
           at bphx.c2ab.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:216)
           at bphx.c2ab.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:462)
           at bphx.c2ab.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory$1.run(HibernateSessionFactory.java:157)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea how to resolve or code such queries?

Is this not working because insert into select queries do not allow composite keys in hibernate class?

Comment: I don't know if such syntax is supported in HQL, but why not select the values before hand in Java, store in local vars and plug them into standard insert HQL?

Comment: Definitely can. But in this way, there will be 2 queries, one for select, one for insert. Looking for an alternative, that can save this performance overhead.

Comment: So let's assume Hibernate supports `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` syntax, how will it know what the values are without selecting first? I feel your assumption `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` is more efficient than SELECT then INSERT is wrong here

Comment: Are you sure `Basoseext2TO` is spelled correctly. Look at the error here: `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:  of: com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.Basoseext2TO [`.

Comment: @zulq yes it is spelled correctly.

Comment: @gerrytan Yes you are right, we will have no performance issue when doing this at database level. But in this case, we would need to communicate with database, once for SELECT and another for INSERT from Java Class, which is an overhead, if INSERT INTO.. SELECT from can be performed in one go.

Comment: @Nidhi recall that Hibernate is an ORM library (Object Relational Mapping). It's not a direct substitute of SQL. Everything need to be mapped to object first. How can Hibernate persist the object without knowing its value beforehand? It sounds like you don't want to be using HIbernate in the first place

Comment: You have a point. Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hibernate documentation, the structure should be: 
`INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement`
Example from the hibernate documentation, you code should look like:

```
<query name="Basoseext2TO_CopyFromExtrFile">
       insert into Basoseext2TO(field_properties)
       select 
       substring(id.thedata, 1, 2),
       substring(id.thedata, 3, 2),
       substring(id.thedata, 5, 3),
       substring(id.thedata, 8, 7),
       substring(id.thedata, 15, 2),
       substring(id.thedata, 17, 10),
       substring(id.thedata, 27, 3976)
       from com.csc.pt.svc.data.to.ExtrfileTO ExtrfileTO
</query>
```

Check here: [HQL Syntax for INSERT](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e2116)